# How to measure effectiveness of using Token Aware connection pool?

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

My team is testing [the token aware connection pool of Astyanax](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Configuration#token-aware). How can we measure effectiveness of the connection pool type, i.e. how can we know how the tokens are distributed in a ring and how client connections are distributed across them?

Our initial tests by counting the number of open connection on network cards show that only 3 out of 4 or more Cassandra instances in a ring are used and the other nodes participate in request processing in a very limited scope.

What other information would help making a valid judgment/verification? Is there an Cassandra/Astyanax API or command line tools to help us out?

Answer (score 2):

Use Opscenter. This will show you how balanced your cluster is, i.e. whether each node has the same amount of data, as well asbeing able to graph the incoming read / write request per node and for your entire cluster. It is free and works with open source Cassandra as well as DSE.  http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-opscenter